# PIVOT with calculated aggregate function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to generate a few reports that display a calculated value for each month where the month values are the columns.

The base query works well to report the months as rows:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(REVENUE)/SUM(HEADCOUNT), 2), MONTH FROM TABLE
GROUP BY MONTH
```

But if I try to pivot the table, I consistently get the ORA-56902 error:' expect aggregate function inside pivot operation':

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT REVENUE, HEADCOUNT, MONTH FROM TABLE
)
PIVOT (ROUND(SUM(REVENUE)/SUM(HEADCOUNT), 2) FOR MONTH IN ('APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC', 'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR'))
```

Is there any way to get PIVOT to see ROUND(SUM(REVENUE)/SUM(HEADCOUNT), 2) as an aggregate function, or is there some other function I should be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise just using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 'APR' THEN REVENUE END)/
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 'APR' THEN HEADCOUNT END
                ), 2) as APR,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 'MAY' THEN REVENUE END)/
             SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH = 'MAY' THEN HEADCOUNT END
                ), 2) as MAY,
       . . .
FROM TABLE;
```

I should point out that you *can* use pivot.  Just calculate the summaries in the subquery and then pivot:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT MONTH, ROUND(SUM(REVENUE) / SUM(HEADCOUNT), 2) as val
      FROM TABLE
      GROUP BY MONTH
     ) m
PIVOT (MAX(val)) FOR MONTH IN ('APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC', 'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR'))
```

Comment: Both these solutions work well. I could have sworn I had tried something similar to your 2nd answer, but I must have left something out.

Answer (score 0):

PIVOT requires an aggregate function, unconditionally.

One way is to calculate your value in the subquery and then do the pivoting.

```
select * 
from (
  select 
    round(sum(revenue)/sum(headcount), 2) val,
    month
  from table
  group by month
)
pivot (
  max(val) 
  for month in ('APR', 'MAY', 'JUN',
  'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 
  'NOV', 'DEC', 'JAN',
  'FEB', 'MAR')
)
```